# WIX BootStapper should prompt Reboot message

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, wix3.11

I am using WIX bootstrapper for installing the newer version of the Installed  MSI. The issue is during the installation if one of my files in the MSI is being used by any of the processes, I want them to be queued for installation and prompt a message box telling the user to reboot the system so that the queued packages will be updated after rebooting.

Comment: Just to be clear, if one of the MSI installs detects a files-in-use situation then you want to abort that install (skip it) and go to the next, returning to the skipped one later on?

Comment: Yes, Skip the file that is in use and queue it for further installation, and system should prompt an reboot message along with the "file in use message". That file should be installed once the system  is rebooted. @PhilDW